# pcap_compile() expression

Tags: c, pcap, libpcap, wifi

I am writing a pcaket sniffer program using libpcap library on the "wlan" interface. I wanted to filter captured packets so that only Beacon frames would be processed. So, I wrote the following code for that:

```
const char *str = "wlan subtype beacon";
printf("debug stmt1\n");

struct bpf_program *fp;
printf("debug stmt2\n");

if((pcap_compile(pkt_handle, fp, str, 1, PCAP_NETMASK_UNKNOWN)==-1)
{
    pcap_perror(pkt_handle, "Compile");
}
printf("debug stmt3\n"):
```

But on compiling, I get a segmentation fault on the pcap_compile() statement:

```
debug stmt1
debug stmt2
Segmentation fault
```

So, what could be the problem?

Opearting System: Ubuntu 10.10

**Update:** 

I moved pcap_compile() statement before pcap_activate() statement. The program works fine and captures only Beacon frames. But, still pcap_compile() seems to be returning -1 and I get the following statement in the output:

```
Compile: 802.11 link-layer types supported only on 802.11
```

What could be the problem? I am using Netgear USB wireless card.

**Update2:**

As suggested by nos, I made the following change:

```
struct bpf_program *fp = (struct bpf_program *)malloc(sizeof(struct bpf_program));
```

But, still I am getting the same message:

```
Compile: 802.11 link-layer types supported only on 802.11
```

Any idea what does that message mean?


**Update 3:**

I also included the following code to make sure that my pcap handle is pointing to the correct interface:

```
int *dlt_buf;
int n;
n = pcap_list_datalinks(pkt_handle, &dlt_buf);
printf("n = %d\n",n);
if(n == -1)
{
    pcap_perror(pkt_handle, "Datalink_list");
}
else
{
    printf("The list of datalinks supported are\n");
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        printf("%d\n",dlt_buf[i]);
    const char *str1 = pcap_datalink_val_to_name(dlt_buf[0]);
    const char *str2 = pcap_datalink_val_to_description(dlt_buf[0]);
    printf("str1 = %s\n",str1);
    printf("str2 = %s\n",str2);
    pcap_free_datalinks(dlt_buf);
}
```

This is the output I got:

```
n = 1
The list of datalinks supported are
127
str1 = IEEE802_11_RADIO
str2 = 802.11 plus radiotap header
```

So, my pcap handle is pointing to the correct interface. But still I am getting that error message.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I was actually using pcap_compile() after the pcap_activate() statement, which was the mistake. On shifting, pcap_compile() part of the code before pcap_activate(), the program is working fine.

Comment: You also need to make `fp` point to something. If the code here works without `fp` being initialized, it's just pure luck.

Comment: @nos  I malloced memory for fp (look update2 in the post). But still the problem persists.

Comment: are you definitely pointing at the right interface?

Comment: @Nim  yes ... I am activating pcap handle on the "wlan1" interface ( iwconfig command shows the interface name as wlan1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The crash, as noted, was because fp wasn't pointing to something.  If a function takes an argument of type "{something} *", that doesn't mean you need to, or even *should*, pass it a variable of type "{something} *"; you should pass it a pointer *value* of that type.

In this case, for example:

```
struct bpf_program *fp;
if((pcap_compile(pkt_handle, fp, str, 1, PCAP_NETMASK_UNKNOWN)==-1)
```

{

is wrong, and

```
struct bpf_program pgm;
if((pcap_compile(pkt_handle, &pgm, str, 1, PCAP_NETMASK_UNKNOWN)==-1)
```

{

is correct.

As for calling `pcap_compile()` before `pcap_activate()`, that's not correct.  You must call it *after* calling `pcap_activate()`, otherwise the `pcap_t` doesn't have a link-layer header type, and `pcap_compile()` won't know the type of link-layer header for which it should generate code.  (I've checked in a fix to libpcap to disallow calling `pcap_compile()` on a not-yet-activated `pcap_t`.)